# Recursion and structural induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, solution-verification

*The set of full binary trees is defined recursively by:*

• Basis step: There is a full binary tree consisting of a single vertex $r$.*

*• Recursive step: If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are disjoint full binary trees, then the tree $T = T_1 \cdot T_2$ formed by
connecting a new root $r$ to each of the roots of the left subtree $T_1$ and right subtree $T_2$ is also a
full binary tree.*

**a) Give recursive definitions of the functions $n(T)$ and $l(T)$ which count the number of vertices and the number of leaves, respectively, in a full binary tree.**

**b) Prove that $n(T) = 2l(T)−1$ for all full binary trees $T$, using structural induction.**

Could anyone verify that my answere is correct?

My answer;

The property can be proof using induction.

Induction basis step: There is a full finary tree consisting of a single vertex $r$. That vertex $r$ also a single leaf node,

Therefore, $l(T) = 1$. Now, $n(T) = 2l(T) - 1 = 2\cdot 1 - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1.$ Hence the propery is true for a single node.

Recursive step: If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are disjoint full binary trees of same height h, then the tree $T = T_1\cdot T_2$ formed by
connecting a new root node r to each of the roots of the left subtree $T_1$ anf right subtree $T_2$ is
also a full binary tree of height h+1. Now assume that the property is true for $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Therefore, $T_1$ and $T_2$ both have $n(T)$ number of vertices and $l(T)$ number of leaves. Now after form a new binary tree, the number of vertices are: $n(T) + n(T) + 1$ [ $1$ for newly root node]. Total $2n(T) + 1$ verices. And the new binary tree contains, $l(T) + l(T)$ number of leaves. In Total $2l(T)$ number of leaves.

Now, $2n(T) + 1 = 2[2l(T)] -1] + 1$ [ since $n(T) = 2l(T) - 1$ is true for $T_1$ and $T_2$]

or $4l(T) -2 +1$

or $4l(T) -1$

or $2\cdot 2l(T) - 1$

The newly binary tree contains $2l(T)$ number of leaves. Hence proved.

Comment: What if $T_1$ and $T_2$ do not have the same height?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would like to highlight that because you are working with **full** binary tree and hence $T_1$ and $T_2$ must have the same height. Also, in the middle of your solution, the index for $T_1$ and $T_2$ are dropped, which is confusing. Thoughour the induction process, we deal with $3$ full binary trees, $T$, $T_1$, and $T_2$.

We assume the conjecture is true for  full binary tree of depth $k$, $T$ and now we are given a tree with depth $k+1$, $T$. We note that $T$ consists of the root and the left subtree of depth $k$, $T_1$ and right subtree $T_2$ of depth $k$.

We know that $T$ consists of $T_1$ and $T_2$, and they are linked by the root. Hence,  $n(T)=n(T_1)+n(T_2)+1$.

Also, the leavess of $T$ are the leaves of $T_1$ and $T_2$, hence $l(T_1)+l(T_2)$.

By our induction hypothesis, we know that $$n(T_1)=2L(T_1)-1$$

$$n(T_2)=2L(T_2)-1$$

Hence, 
\begin{align}n(T)&=n(T_1)+n(T_2)+1 \\
&= (2l(T_1)-1) + (2l(T_2)-1)+1\\
&=2(l(T_1)+l(T_2))-1\\
&= 2l(T)-1\end{align}